# React-native: Binding scene to NavigationBar

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigator

I'm putting together this Ask/Answer App, and came across this hurdle:

I want to trigger a function in a scene from the navigationBar. Similar to a Login app I have a button in the NavigationBar to Submit an answer:

```
RightButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    if (route.name=='TextInputView'){
     return <TouchableHighlight
             underlayColor="transparent"
             style={{ marginRight:13,  marginTop:0}}
             onPress={() => this.refs.TextInputView.submitSolution()}>
        <Text style={ styles.leftNavButtonText }>Done</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    }
```

the renderscene(route,navigator) looks like so:

```
if (route.name == 'TextInputView'){
  return <TextInputView ref="TextInputView" navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps}/>
}
```

and of course in the "TextInputView" component I have a "submitSolution" function...

problem is if I'm in the scene and press the "Done" - I always get:
"undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.refs.TextInputView')

as always: thanks for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you can do it by keeping everything related to the submission in the scene itself.

How?

You do it by injecting a button in the navbar on-demand.

Here's a solution I created for a project I'm working on:
https://rnplay.org/apps/dS31zw

The idea is to supply the navbar route with an object that has a label and a function (and whatever you like.. e.g. icons.)

As a bonus, you can inject the title too!

Note: this trick depends on componentWillMount() being invoked before NavigationBarRouteMapper does it work. If this change in the future, it will definitely break it.  But it works flawlessly now!

```
'use strict';

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactNative from 'react-native';

const {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Navigator,
  Alert,
  TouchableHighlight
} = ReactNative;

class Home extends Component {

  //This trick depends on that componentWillMount fires before the navbar is created
  componentWillMount() {
        this.props.route.navbarTitle = "Home";

        this.props.route.rightNavButton = {
            text: "Button",
            onPress: this._doSomething.bind(this)
        };
    }

  _doSomething() {
    Alert.alert(
      'Awesome, eh?',
      null,
      [
        {text: 'Indeed'},
      ]
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>You are home</Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

class AppContainer extends Component {

    renderScene(route, navigator) {
        switch(route.name) {
            case "Home":
      //You must pass route as a prop for this trick to work properly
            return <Home route={route} navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps}  />
            default:
            return (
        <Text route={route}
        style={styles.container}>
            Your route name is probably incorrect {JSON.stringify(route)}
            </Text>
      );
        }
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        navigationBar={
          <Navigator.NavigationBar
            style={ styles.navbar }
            routeMapper={ NavigationBarRouteMapper } />
        }

        initialRoute={{ name: 'Home' }}
        renderScene={ this.renderScene }

      />
    );
  }
}

//Nothing fancy here, except for checking for injected buttons.
var NavigationBarRouteMapper = {
  LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    if(route.leftNavButton) {
      return (
        <TouchableHighlight
        style={styles.leftNavButton}
        underlayColor="transparent"
        onPress={route.leftNavButton.onPress}>
          <Text style={styles.navbarButtonText}>{route.leftNavButton.text}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      );
    }
    else if(route.enableBackButton) {
      return (
        <TouchableHighlight
        style={styles.leftNavButton}
        underlayColor="transparent"
        onPress={() => navigator.pop() }>
          <Text style={styles.navbarButtonText}>Back</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      );
    }
  },
  RightButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    if(route.rightNavButton) {
      return (
        <TouchableHighlight
        style={styles.rightNavButton}
        underlayColor="transparent"
        onPress={route.rightNavButton.onPress}>
          <Text style={styles.navbarButtonText}>{route.rightNavButton.text}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      );
    }
  },
  Title(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    return (<Text style={styles.navbarTitle}>{route.navbarTitle || route.name}</Text>);
  }
};

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    marginTop: 66
  },
  navbar: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
  navbarTitle: {
    marginVertical: 10,
    fontSize: 17
  },
  leftNavButton: {
    marginVertical: 10,
    paddingLeft: 8,
 },
  rightNavButton: {
    marginVertical: 10,
    paddingRight: 8,
  },
  navbarButtonText: {
    fontSize: 17,
    color: "#007AFF"
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AppContainer', () => AppContainer);
```

Comment: Nice solution!! Been struggling for a while with exactly this. Many thanks for the hint! 
How would you assign an initial button? You inject buttons per scene, but I would like to assign a "Menu" button from root.

Comment: @funkysoulzh In the proper method inside NavigationBarRouteMapper, eg LeftButton, add your if-condition clause and add the button inside it. Just like how I'm adding the back button in the LeftButton method. But in your case, you might want to check for the route name.

Comment: Hey Ahmed, I realized that my logic was crooked, as I'm starting with an initial scene I can also attach the "initial" buttons to that scene. 
When you sit in front of something for too long you suddenly don't see how easy it is ;-). Anyway thanks for the above!

Comment: @funkysoulzh That works too, haha! Glad to be of help.